# Transmission of modifier keys in remote desktop (Ventura)

Tags: shortcut, ventura, apple-remote-desktop

Using Apple remote desktop in Ventura, modifier keys are not transmitted. Thus, troubles start by entering the password of a user containing capitals. Even copy / paste just works using the menu.
What is the solution?

Comment: What version of ARD [& clients] 3.9.6 is new for Ventura.

Comment: Version 3.0 (585.1)

Comment: Can you double check? 3.0 is from 2006. 3.9.6 is needed for Ventura - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12

Comment: got it. In fact, it's not "Apple Remote Desktop" that I use. I'm using a system immanent screen sharing, invoked from a finder window. Thus, I should use the app instead?